# Tesseract is Not Working At Another PC

Tags: tesseract

I tried to use tesseract on my project at C# and i finished it works great at my computer but when i try to use this project at another PC first it gave vcruntime140.dll error, i solved it and after it works great except OCR, and i use exactly same version of tesseract at 2 PC. I will call my computer source.

Source PC
Windows10 
Project written at VS2017 C#
.NET Framework 3.5
Tesseract Version

tesseract 4.0.0-alpha.20180109
leptonica-1.74.4
libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.0) : libpng 1.6.24 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.3 : libopenjp2 2.1.0

Target PC
Windows7
It has all dependicies
Tesseract Version

tesseract 4.0.0-alpha.20180109
leptonica-1.74.4
libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.0) : libpng 1.6.24 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.3 : libopenjp2 2.1.0

I know it has all image format's library but i tried png and tiff both with my last hope =)

Thanks!
Abdullah

Comment: Unless there's code involved, this question appears to be system-level and off-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

It throws this when OCR try to work ;

"the exception was created by an invocation target"